# Microsoft SQL JDBC Spring boot configuration does not work when database name is not in the url

Tags: sql-server, spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a spring boot JDBC **Cofiguration A** as below which works well,

**Configuration A**

```
spring.datasource.sqlserver.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=my-testdb
spring.datasource.sqlserver.user=user_101@server-product1
spring.datasource.sqlserver.password=password_101    
spring.datasource.sqlserver.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**Configuration B** below does not. Note that the url string does not have the database name in it. The database name is specified in a separate line, as one would expect to configure.

```
spring.datasource.sqlserver.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433
spring.datasource.sqlserver.user=user_101@server-product1
spring.datasource.sqlserver.password=password_101
spring.datasource.sqlserver.database=my-testdb 
spring.datasource.sqlserver.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Cannot figure out why the database name cannot be specified in a separate line and has to be in the URL. Can anyone mention why this does not work?

Other configuration : Spring Boot, sqljdbc41.jar

Answer (score 0):

Well that's how the Microsoft's SQL Server / Azure JDBC driver works, database name is a mandatory part of the URL, and not given in a "database" attribute.

Technically, it may be related to the fact that databases in SQL Server behave rather autonomously, they each have their own set of catalog views, you cannot switch between databases freely etc.